# want to create user info panel like google with extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, frontend

Its a weird question but i hope i can get some suggestions or examples from you guys i wanna create a User info panel like google let me show you in image
[image]

now here is my picture with xtype: 'image', in it and i am using extjs 6

[image]
i want the same thing just like google here
help me with any suggestion thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write tool-tip with target property.

```
Ext.create('Ext.tip.ToolTip', {
            target: Ext.getCmp('image-1021').getEl(),
            anchor: 'bottom',
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [{}]
});
```

[image]

for more information you can refer this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tip.ToolTip.html)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving brief info the right-top side where image is shown, on its click show tooltip with top anchor.Check if you are able to add image/label/buttons inside tooltip as items.If this is not possible you will need to create XTemplate and add this xtemplate inside tooltip.
Any question further ?